How to create error bars for random forest variable importance plots in R?
I am running a multi-class RF model with cross-validation. For each class, I would like to plot feature importance with error bars calculated from 10 folds. I would be grateful for advice. I have managed to create a data frame with the variable importance figures for each variable (4) and each fold (10).
I am not sure to create a data frame that creates the mean and SD aggregated across the folds so that it results in 4 rows representing each variable. I would like to then plot feature importance with error bars for each class.
Here is code to run a model and image of what I am trying to achieve:

# Load necessary libraries
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
df= iris

# Define the control using a 10-fold cross-validation
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, savePredictions="final", index=createFolds(df$Species, k=10))

# Train the model
model <- train(Species ~ ., data=df, method="rf", trControl=train_control, importance=TRUE)

# Function to extract variable importance for each fold and species
get_fold_importance <- function(fold_index, data) {
  fold_data <- data[fold_index, ]
  fold_model <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=fold_data, importance=TRUE)
  importance_df <- as.data.frame(importance(fold_model))
  importance_df$Species <- unique(fold_data$Species)
  return(importance_df)
}

# Extract variable importance for each fold
fold_importance <- lapply(train_control$index, get_fold_importance, data=df)

# Combine the importance from each fold into a single data frame
importance_df <- bind_rows(fold_importance)





Can't see errors in model output, which errors would you visualize exactly?

Thank you for your reply. I suppose I need to extract the variable importance for each of the 10 folds and then calculate the error bars. I am not sure how to extract the var imp for each fold.
